# table is not binding in angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, ajax

Hello everyone I am trying to  bind a table in angulajs. I am getting data from database in table and trying to fill that table.
Here I did

```
$scope.getPageDetails = function () {
    $http.get('/api/privilege/getpagedetails/')
        .success(function (data, status) {
            $scope.Page = data;
            console.log($scope.Page);
        }).error(function () {
        });
}
```

then i get the data in $scope.Page which is defined as `$scope.Page = [];` here i am attaching the console image that i am getting data in $scope.page[image]

and here is my table

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                ID
                            </th>

                            <th>
                                PageName
                            </th>

                            <th>
                                PageUrl
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr ng-repeat="Page in Pages">
                            <td>{{Page.id}}</td>
                            <td>{{Page.pageName}}</td>
                            <td>{{Page.pageUrl}}</td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="checkbox"  value="Edit" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

please help where I am missing I will be very thankful to you all.

Comment: `$scope.Page` should be `$scope.Pages`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your view you are iterating over `Pages`, but I dont see it defined in your controller.

Change

```
$scope.Page = data;
```

to

```
$scope.Pages = [data];
```

Final Code
HTML:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            ID
                        </th>

                        <th>
                            PageName
                        </th>

                        <th>
                            PageUrl
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="Page in Pages">
                        <td>{{Page.id}}</td>
                        <td>{{Page.pageName}}</td>
                        <td>{{Page.pageUrl}}</td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="checkbox"  value="Edit" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

controller:

```
$scope.getPageDetails = function () {
$http.get('/api/privilege/getpagedetails/')
    .success(function (data, status) {
        $scope.Pages = [data];
    }).error(function () {
    });
```

}

EDIT: if your data is an object make it an array, so ng-repeat can iterate over it

Comment: what should i have to do in n-repeat

Comment: If you point to the correct reference in your controller (changing `$scope.Pages = data;`), no work needed on the ng-repeat. Angular will do the rest

Comment: Not woking sir i changes the page to pages but not binding in ng-repeat

Comment: What is the content of `data` if it just an object you can wrap it within an array, because ng-repeat works with arrays something like `$scope.Pages = [data];` in order to work, but If this will be used only once I dont see the use of using ng-repeat, you could just build the table with the object.

Comment: I did this<tbody>
                        <tr ng-repeat="Pages in Page">
                            <td>{{Pages.id}}</td>
                            <td>{{Pages.pageName}}</td>
                            <td>{{Pages.pageUrl}}</td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="checkbox" value="Edit" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
But this is not binding..

Comment: I've updated with the full code, assuming that in `data` is a simple object

Answer (score 1):

```
$scope.getPageDetails = function () {
    $http.get('/api/privilege/getpagedetails/')
        .success(function (data, status) {
            $scope.Pages = data; //change page to pages in whole code,  
                                 //no need to change any thing in html page
            console.log($scope.Pages);
        }).error(function () {
        });
}
```

Comment: what you are getting here is normal object with one key and value json.

Comment: ng-repeat works on array of objects..
here you can directly bind the $scope with the view.

Comment: $scope.getPageDetails = function () {
    $http.get('/api/privilege/getpagedetails/')
        .success(function (data, status) {
            $scope.Page = data; //sorry dont change here remove ng-
                                               //repeat from the html file
            console.log($scope.Page);
        }).error(function () {
        });
}

Comment: <table class="table table-bordered table-hover"><thead><tr><th>ID</th><th>PageName</th><th>PageUrl</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>{{Page.id}}</td><td>{{Page.pageName}}</td><td>{{Page.pageUrl}}</td><td><input type="checkbox"  value="Edit" /></td></tr></tbody></table>

Comment: @Gaurav_0093 use ng-model in the td tag like

Answer (score 0):

`$scope.Page` in controller vs `Pages` in your HTML ng-repeat binding, you need to write `$scope.Pages` :)

Answer (score 0):

Change `$scope.Page = data` to `$scope.Pages = data`.

Comment: yes I changed it according to you but what should i Do in ng-repeat